# Does Python Tools for Visual Studio support discovering unit tests when using any python interpreter other than IronPython?

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I have a couple of ActiveState python 2.7 interpreters, and one IronPython interpreter in my Python environments setup and in the same project. Whenever I switch to make IronPython interpreter the active one, Visual Studio Test Explorer is able to discover and run the tests. Switching to any other interpreter fails to discover any tests (so 0 tests are run if I do "run all"). Interestingly running 'python.exe -m unittest discover' works for any of those interpreters. 
Is this a known issue, or is anyone able to use non-IronPython interpreter and still discover unit tests in Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Comment: Unit test functionality in PTVS is not IronPython-specific (as a matter of fact, CPython is the most tested implementation). But there may well be something specific about ActivePython that makes a difference. File a bug on https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS

Comment: There is something odd going on, I get mixed results with various CPython interpeters, up to the point where the same interpreter (to be specific - the one that ships with Maya) _works_ (i.e. discovers the tests) only if I put its lib folder setting to a non-existing folder, but fails if the lib folder is setup correctly...

Comment: I am using Python 64-bit 2.7 from [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and Test Explorer is finding the test.